# Script php desde consola linux error mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un script en PHP que lo ejecuto desde las consola de linux, este script recorre una tabla de base de datos y va actualizando uno a uno los registros en otra tabla, el problema es que de manera aleatoria, el mysql empieza a tirar error en las consultas cuando en realidad están bien, y cuando esto sucede todas las consultas que siguen dan error.

```
$mysql=new CMySLQ();
$sql=$mysql->Consultar("SELECT * FROM persona WHERE fecha_baja is NULL ORDER BY codigo ASC");
while($p=mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
  $sql2=$mysql->Consultar("UPDATE persona_existentes SET sigue_ok=Now() WHERE persona=".$p->codigo);
  if(mysql_affected_rows( $mysql->ObtenerManejador()) != 1 ) {
     echo 'fallo al actualizar la persona '.$p->codigo; die;
  } 
}
```

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%timeout%';
+-------------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                       | Value    |
+-------------------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout                     | 10       |
| deadlock_timeout_long               | 50000000 |
| deadlock_timeout_short              | 10000    |
| delayed_insert_timeout              | 300      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout         | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout            | 50       |
| innodb_print_lock_wait_timeout_info | OFF      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout          | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout                 | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout                   | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout                    | 30       |
| net_write_timeout                   | 60       |
| slave_net_timeout                   | 3600     |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout            | 60       |
| wait_timeout                        | 28800    |
+-------------------------------------+----------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in....  Este error perteneceria a la consulta de UPDATE, es raro, porque la consulta esta ok

Comment: Agregale if (!$sql1)  die("mySQL error: ". mysql_error()); antes del while(...) y fijate si tira algún otro error.

Comment: Parece que el error está aquí: `if(mysql_affected_rows( $mysql->ObtenerManejador()) != 1 ) {` prueba a cambiarlo por esto: **`if(mysql_affected_rows() != 1 ) {`** Aunque el código no es *coherente*... la consulta puede encontrar más de una fila  según el `WHERE` y actualizar por tanto más de una. Al preguntar si es `!= 1` indicará como que el código falló, siendo falso en ese hipotético caso.

Comment: mysql_error() me arroja este resultado "MySQL server has gone away"

Comment: En realidad deberia actualizar si o si un solo registro, ya que el campo "persona" en la tabla persona_existentes es clave primaria, por lo que no podria repetirse

Comment: Ya. Y probaste a ponerlo así: `if(mysql_affected_rows() != 1 ) {`  ... ¿sigue dando error?

Comment: En la configuracion de mysql pase  de max_allowed_packet  = 256M a max_allowed_packet  = 512M y pareciera que estaria funcionando

Comment: El error que te da no parece tener que ver con el código de tu programa sino es más un tema de infraestructura. Fijate este link. https://www.siteground.es/kb/error-mysql-server-gone-away/